# Evaluating the Tensor Product of Smooth Tensor Fields at a Point

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products

I'm reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, and in Chapter 12 I've hit a minor but annoying wrinkle regarding tensor fields. Proposition 12.25(a) states that for any two covariant tensor fields $A$ and $B$ and smooth map $F : M \to N$,

> $F^* (A \otimes B) = F^* A \otimes F^* B$

where $F^* A$ is the pullback of $A$ by $F$. Proving the proposition is straightforward enough, but in doing so I make use of $(A \otimes B)_p = A_p \otimes B_p$, which seems intuitively obvious and is actually the definition of the tensor product of tensor fields in another text. But unfortunately, Lee never explicitly states this, and it seemingly can't be derived from any other information in the chapter. In fact, after defining a covariant tensor field on a smooth manifold $M$ as a section of the tensor bundle
$$ T^k T^* M = \coprod_{p \in M} T^k(T^*_p M), $$
(where $T^k(T^*_p M)$ is the vector space of covariant $k$-tensors on $T_p M$) Lee simply states that any such section $A$ can be written (using the summation convention) as
$$ A = A_{i_1 \dots i_k} dx^{i_1} \otimes \dots \otimes dx^{i_k}, $$
without any mention of how one is to evaluate the given tensor product of covector fields at a point.

Is there any way I can arrive at the desired result using strictly what is presented by Lee, or am I being overly pedantic and should just move on?

Comment: Lee defines the point wise pullback just before Prop 12.25?

Comment: @JackLee  This is natural, but you might want to clarify this. I don't think you explicitly define $(A \otimes B)_p = A_p \otimes B_p$.

Comment: @Oiler You're right, but my issue isn't with the pullback, it's with the tensor product. It's clear that $(F^*(A \otimes B))_p(v_1,\dots,v_{k+l}) = (A \otimes B)_{F(p)}(dF_p(v_1),\dots,dF_p(v_{k+l}))$. However, aside from a gut assumption and reference to another book, it wasn't clear to me how to split up the tensor product of the fields so that we can obtain $A_{F(p)}(dF_p(v_1), \dots, dF_p(v_k))B_{F(p)}(dF_p(v_{k+1}), \dots, dF_p(v_{k+l})))$and then move on to the final result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm surprised by this question, because my writing is more often criticized for being *too* pedantic! Did you really have to wonder what $A\otimes B$ means? I'm having a hard time imagining what it could possibly mean other than $(A\otimes B)_p = A_p\otimes B_p$. But you're right, I didn't actually write that definition anywhere. To forestall any future confusion, I've added it to my [correction list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/ISM/).

Comment: I was surprised too, and even more surprised how the OP detected this subtle fact!!

Comment: Haha, I suppose it is surprising, and I did assume it was true when first working out the problem without realizing. It just made me slightly wary when I realized the only explicit definition of the tensor product was in regards to tensors and not tensor fields. And may I say, as a self-student who's been out of university for over ten years with no professors or colleagues to pester with questions, I appreciate excessive pedantry, especially in introductory material!

Comment: The level of detail of your books is very appreciated by students. Keep the good work up Prof. Lee!

Comment: Sir, could i know when the new book on bundles came out? I really enjoyed your books on manifolds.

Comment: @SiKucing: My book on bundles is still very much under construction. I can't give an accurate release date yet, but it will probably be at least a year from now.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait for it.

Comment: @JackLee: You meant new book on bundles or updating section of bundles of smooth manifolds? If it is new book, I guess it is probably  similar to Steenrod book or Milnor char. classes?

Comment: @C.F.G: I was referring to a new book that I'm working on, which will probably be titled "Introduction to Bundles." Although it will have some overlap with the books by Steenrod and Milnor, it will be very different from those, mainly because it will include a lot more differential geometry.

Comment: @JackLee: Wow,  it will include a lot more differential geometry!!! It remember me the Loring TU's last book. anyway sounds interesting as well as your other GTM books. I am waiting impatiently for that. Any small assists that can I do to speed up the release date?

Comment: Your book was great, but small details like what the OP picked up on can be important when you're self-learning - which is what I was. In a classroom situation, this can easily be put right. Of course you can always ask on SE or some other forum ...